# I am using android studio 2.1.2 and am trying to get the latest facebook sdk, gradle seem to have an error

Tags: android, facebook

[Error][1]
My build.gradle(Project: MyApplication) file is:

android
 {

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "itp231.dba.nyp.com.myproject2016"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}
repositories {

```
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
```

}
using json to get user id,email once logged in

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:19.1.0'
// Android SDK
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'
// Audience Network SDK. Only versions 4.6.0 and above are available
//compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.13.2'
// Account Kit
//compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.13.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

}

[Error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ydby.png).com/PFDzS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with android studio's version

try adding below dependency in your module's gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

}

Comment: I don't know why someone gave a negative vote to an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you don't have install `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'` click on Install repository and sync the project or try with another version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` that you already have installed